# SwiftUI Custom Camera- Camera Preview keeps crashing

Tags: ios, iphone, swiftui, ios-camera

My goal is to build a custom camera for my app. At the moment, I'm just trying to get the live preview working, however for some reason my camera preview keeps crashing. I'm not exactly sure why the camera preview causes my app to crash. Is there a bug in SwiftUI I am unaware of? Here's the complete code below, the camera preview is at the bottom. Any little bit of help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

---

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

struct LiveCamera: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        CameraView()
    }
}

struct LiveCamera_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LiveCamera()
    }
}

struct CameraView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @StateObject var camera  = CameraModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            // Going to be the camera view
            Color.black
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
            VStack {
                // Dismiss button back to oringinal screen 
                Button(action: {
                    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "multiply")
                        .font(.system(size: 40, weight: .semibold))
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white.opacity(0.9))
                        .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.6), radius: 1, x: 0, y: 2)
                })
                .offset(x: 150)
                
                Spacer()

                // Botttom toolbar for Live camera view
                HStack {
                    
                    // switch camera button
                    Button(action: {
                        
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "arrow.triangle.2.circlepath.camera")
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    })
                    .padding(.leading)
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    // If taken showing Live buttons
                    if camera.isTaken {
                        
                        Spacer()
                        // Stop live recording button
                        Button(action: {
                            camera.isTaken.toggle()
                        }, label: {
                            
                            ZStack {
                                Circle()
                                    .fill(Color.red)
                                    .frame(width: 65, height: 65)
                                Circle()
                                    .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2)
                                    .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
                            }
                        })
                        Spacer()
                        
                    } else {
                        
                        // start live recording button
                        Button(action: {
                            camera.isTaken.toggle()
                        }, label: {
                            
                            ZStack {
                                Circle()
                                    .fill(Color.white)
                                    .frame(width: 65, height: 65)
                                Circle()
                                    .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2)
                                    .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
                            }
                            
                        })
                    }
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    // camera flash/ light button
                    Button(action: {
                        
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "bolt.circle")
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    })
                    .padding(.trailing)
                }
                .frame(height: 75)
            }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            camera.check()
        })
    }
}


// Camera Model...

class CameraModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var isTaken  = false
    
    @Published var session = AVCaptureSession()
    
    @Published var alert = false
    
    // since were going to read pic data
    @Published var output = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
    
    // preview
    @Published var preview : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
    
    
    func check() {
        
        // first checking camera got permission...
        switch AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video) {
        case .authorized:
            setUp()
            return
        // Setting up session
        case .notDetermined:
            // return for permission
            AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { (status) in
                
                if status {
                    self.setUp()
                }
            }
        case .denied:
            self.alert.toggle()
            return
            
        default:
            return
        }
    }
    
    func setUp() {
        
        // setting up camera
        
        do {
            // setting configuration
            self.session.beginConfiguration()
            
            // change for your own...
          let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .front)
            
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device!)
            
            // checking and adding to session
            if self.session.canAddInput(input) {
                self.session.addInput(input)
            }
            
            // same for output
            if self.session.canAddOutput(self.output) {
                self.session.addOutput(self.output)
            }
            
            self.session.commitConfiguration()
        }
        catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}

// setting view for preview

struct CameraPreview: UIViewRepresentable {
    @ObservedObject var camera : CameraModel
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        
        let view = UIView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        
        camera.preview = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: camera.session)
        camera.preview.frame = view.frame
        
        // Your own properties....
        camera.preview.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        view.layer.addSublayer(camera.preview)
        
        // start camera session
        camera.session.startRunning()
        
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: This code seems to work on SwiftUI's preview but crashed on the Device because I needed to a description explaining to the user how/why the app uses the camera.

Comment: So to fix it, you need to add in The app's `Info.plist` , an `NSCameraUsageDescription` key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

Comment: Hi Cedric, thanks for getting back to me. Ive done that. Privacy Usage  Description in Info.plist, that's not it.

Comment: Which device are you using to run?

Comment: Im running it on an iPhone 11 Pro max